# How to get shell prompt in Python

Tags: python, shell, command-prompt

The prompt on the server I'm working on contains useful info. I wonder if there's a way to get that string in Python, so that I can write an automated program that can have specific behaviors according to the machine (can be known from prompt) on which it is executed.

Some people suggest `/bin/bash`, but it doesn't work. It just enters the bash program, whose prompt is different. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JakeGould I don't understand you question. I made it clear that the prompt is useful, but I don't know where I comes from, the server is from school and is public

Comment: Try `uname -n`, `whoami`, `os.getcwd()`, etc..

Comment: @false the first one works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in bash

```
echo $PS1
```

to see prompt definiton.

Probably you could find this definiton also in `~/.bashrc` , `~/.profile` , `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`

But prompt can use special marks to get some information and you can't get what program was used.